# difference between putting head file(.h) at the beginning and end of another file(.h or .cpp)

Tags: c++

Recently , I was compiling libfacebookcpp on mac os. I found a strange usage which I can't understand.
There are two files, AuthorizedObject.hpp and List.hpp. 
At the end of file AuthorizedObject.hpp,there is one line :#include "List.hpp".Now I compile successfully. But 
when I move that line to the beginning, error occurs. The skeleton of the codes are:

```
//AuthorizedObject.hpp
class AuthorizedObject
{
public:
... 
template<class TType>
void _GetConnection(const ::std::string& uri, List<TType> *list) const
{
    LIBFACEBOOKCPP_CHKARG(list);

    Json::Value value;
    request_->GetResponse(uri, &value);

    list->Deserialize(*this, value);
}
...
}
#include "List.hpp" //end

----------------------------------------------------------
//List.hpp 
#include "AuthorizedObject.hpp"
class LIBFACEBOOKCPP_API List : public AuthorizedObject
{
private: // private classes
...
}
```

I guess if put that line(#include "List.h") at the beginning of AuthorizedObject.hpp, the two files include each other by circle. So the compiler don't know how to compile.But put that line at the end will solve this problem? Why? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try to remove line: #include "List.h" //end

Comment: It should be noted that this diverts from preprocessor best practices to the point of being ugly mess. Don't follow this example!

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in what order classes/functions/... are defined, for example:

```
#include "one.h"
void foo(bar &);

// Will result into:
class bar {};
void foo(bar&);
```

Which is valid code. On the other hand:

```
void foo(bar &);
#include "one.h"

// Will result into statements in different order:
void foo(bar&);
class bar {};
```

Which means using `class bar` before it was declared, thus error. You also may need to make sure that no declaration will be processed twice ([UmNyobe already covered that partially](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13376496/1149736)):

```
#if !defined( MY_HEADER_INCLUDED_)
# define MY_HEADER_INCLUDED_
// Complete content goes here
#endif /* !defined( MY_HEADER_INCLUDED_) */
```

This way when you include file for the first time, `MY_HEADER_INCLUDED_` won't be defined (contents will be "placed" inside the code). The second time (you will include it in the circle) `MY_HEADER_INCLUDED_` will be defined and therefore complete body will be skipped.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, that's the problem. You're wrong that the compiler doesn't know how to compile - it does, you're just using it wrong :).

The include guards at the beginning of `AuthorizedObject.hpp` (I assume it has include guards or a `#pragma once` directive) will define `AUTHORIZED_OBJECT_H` (or similar). After that, you include `List.h`, which in turn includes the header `AuthorizedObject.hpp`. Because the include guard macro was already defined, the definition of `AuthorizedObject` is skipped, so `List` doesn't know about the type, but is uses it, so you get the error.

If you move the include at the end, the definition of `AuthorizedObject` was already processed by the compiler, so using it inside `List.h` is valid.